# Cloudflare redirecting to from one domain to another?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cloudflare

Is it possible to redirect from **domainA.com** to **domainB.com** without **domainA.com** having any DNS records?

I have two domains that I need to direct to another domain- the two domains don't have any other function than to be redirected. On Cloudflare these domains do not have any DNS records. Can you do this without directing them to a server and do the operations via .htacces, but by simply configuring it on CF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain needs to have DNS records running through our proxy for our [PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) to work.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.